# Is nonnegative hierarchical time series reconciliation implemented in sktime?

Tags: forecasting, sktime, reconciliation

I am using sktime to perform time series forecasting and hierarchical reconciliation. For the latter I am using the ReconcilerForecaster class with the OLS method ([ReconcilerForecaster in sktime](https://www.sktime.net/en/latest/api_reference/auto_generated/sktime.forecasting.reconcile.ReconcilerForecaster.html?highlight=reconcilerforecaster)).
My question is: is there a way to obtain **nonnegative** revised forecasts after the reconciliation step using the ReconcilerForecaster class in sktime?

I am aware of other implementations of this restriction for hierarchical TS reconciliation, like the library hierarchicalforecast ([HierarchicalForecast library](https://nixtla.github.io/hierarchicalforecast/methods.html)) where the MinTrace and OptimalCombination reconciliation classes allow to define the restriction for getting always nonnegative revised forecasts. But, is there a way to specify this restriction in sktime?